# Error: Use of undeclared type 'SCNView'

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, scenekit

Im doing a transition from Obj-C to Swift and after 5 seconds I'm stuck :/

1. I have a storyboard with a SCNView object
2. I drag a connection to my view controller
3. Xcode writes out `@IBOutlet var scene: SCNView!`

I get the error:

```
'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type '<<error type>>'

Use of undeclared type 'SCNView'
```

What is this?

I'm using latest Xcode 6.3.

Comment: Have you imported SceneKit?

Comment: oooops can't believe I missed that :). Stupid question, how do I import SceneKit in the Swift file? (feels like I'm beginning to learn how to walk again)

Comment: Fixed it. Love your book BTW!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell Swift about the frameworks (modules) you intend to use in a source code file with the `import` statement, just like you tell ObjC about such using `#import`or `#include`.

```
import SceneKit 

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: SCNView!
    // ...
}
```

This both makes the classes, functions and other symbols available for use in your source file and makes Xcode link in the SceneKit framework binary when building your app.